# How to go to the highest parent using jquery.mmenu

Tags: mmenu

I have created a menu using jquery.mmenu. I have submenu's within the menu's and the functionality works as expected. However with jquery.mmenu you can only go back to the closest parent. I want to add a new link which will allow the user to go back to the most upper parent in one go.

So lets say I have a menu like this: Food --> drinks --> soft drinks --> coca cola
If the user is at the coca cola level, I want a link that brings the user back to Food. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from a jquery.mmenu developer directly (FrDH)

```
   var $menu = $("#my-menu").mmenu();
    var API = $menu.data( "mmenu" );

    $("#some-elem").on("click", function() {
        API.closeAllPanels();
    });
```

He admitted it was somehow not in the API docs yet. He will add it later on.